# How to calculate this kind of summation?

Tags: polynomials, summation

I'm now on the first chapter of the book 'Mathematical Methods For Physics and Engineering' and I came across this summation.

$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^{n}$$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k>j}^{n}  a_ja_k$

How to do this computation ?I tried searching for an explanation in the internet but I got none.

Comment: Is the equal sign supposed to be there?

Comment: @fleablood nope. It was a mistake i removed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloaded the book. https://www.zuj.edu.jo/download/mathematical-methods-for-physics-and-engineering-riley-hobson-pdf/

Are you doing equation 1.14?

$\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\sum\limits_{k>j}^n \alpha_j\alpha_k = \frac {a_{n-2}}{a_n}$?

In the case the summation means:

$\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\sum\limits_{k>j}^n \alpha_j\alpha_k=$

$\sum\limits_{j=1}^n(\sum\limits_{k>j}^n \alpha_j\alpha_k)=$

$\sum\limits_{j=1}^n(\color{blue}{\sum\limits_{k\text{ is any natural number} > j\text{ up to the final summand of } n}^n} \alpha_j\alpha_k)=$

$\sum\limits_{j=1}^n(\sum\limits_{k=j+1}^n \alpha_j\alpha_k)=$

$\sum\limits_{j=1}^n(\alpha_j\alpha_{j+1} + \alpha_j\alpha_{j+2} + ..... + \alpha_j\alpha_n) = $

$\color{blue}{\sum\limits_{j\text { is every natural number from } 1\text{ to } n}^n}(\alpha_j\alpha_{j+1} + \alpha_j\alpha_{j+2} + ..... + \alpha_j\alpha_n) = $

$(\alpha_1\alpha_2 + ................... + \alpha_1\alpha_n) + $

$(\alpha_2\alpha_3 + ........... + \alpha_2\alpha_n) + $

.........

$(\alpha_{n-2}\alpha_{n-1} + \alpha_{n-2}\alpha_n) + $

$(\alpha_{n-1}\alpha_{n})$

....

In short this is the way we write "the sum of all possible $\alpha_j\alpha_k$ where $k > j$ and and $j,k \le n$".

Comment: Yes , that is the equation i was seeking the explanation for. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=j+1}^n1=\sum_{j=1}^n(n-(j+1)+1)=\sum_{j=1}^n(j-1)$$

Comment: You have a good sense of divination to understand what the sum of the OP is!

Comment: I am still not clarified but I would like to know how you wrote the summation sign. Do you know a way to write it in android

Comment: @Luke_hog, What is your question? Do you want to calculate the sum ?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net if only i could send you the picture , it would be more clear to you. I am just a beginner so i cant post picture.

Comment: @Luke_hog have you tried use $\mathrm\LaTeX$ to write the math? Google some commands and you will see that is easy to use.

Comment: @manooooh thanks for you advice i corrected it.

Comment: "Google some commands and you will see that is easy to use. "  Yeah, we make it sound so easy.... LaTex and MathJax is a pain in the ass and hard as hell for novices.  Admittedly we *must* learn how to do it in order to make ourselves understood and there's no getting around that.  But we shouldn't pretend that it's easy for novices. \$\sum_{stuff}^{buff} thing_{n}\$ is what we type to get $\sum_{stuff}^{buff} thing_{n}$